# What are possible reasons for not being able to access os functions in aiofiles?

Tags: python, python-import, attributeerror, python-aiofiles

I work with `aiofiles` module. In the code, I have imported `aiofiles`, and tried to call `makedirs` function:

```
import asyncio
import aiofiles

asyncio.run(aiofiles.os.makedirs('downloads', exist_ok=True))
```

I got:

```
AttributeError: module 'aiofiles' has no attribute 'os'
```

Setup:

- aiofiles 23.1.0
- Python 3.10 environment, created with conda (22.9.0).
- Modules are installed with pip
- Windows

I found a simple workaround:

```
from aiofiles import os as aioos 

asyncio.run(aioos.makedirs('downloads', exist_ok=True))
```

It runs without problems. Yet I did find examples where `makedirs` was called exactly like `aiofiles.os.makedirs`.

What is in my setup might be wrong, so that I cannot use `aiofiles.os.makedirs` with just `import aiofiles`?

Comment: If you named a file `aiofiles.py`, don't name it that.

Comment: You're probably supposed to explicitly `import aiofiles.os` before trying to use `aiofiles.os`.

Comment: @deceze Yep, as in what is probably the "[examples](https://superfastpython.com/aiofiles-for-asyncio-in-python/#Make_Directories)".